# Dynamic web application structure from maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am new to maven and was trying to generate a sample web application using `mvn :archetype:generate`.
The generated project structure was not inline with the structure which we see in dynamic web application from eclipse.

Google result says i need to create a custom archetypeid for this. I want to generate the project structure from maven which is same as that of dynamic web application in eclipse.

How do i go about achieving this?

Comment: You are better off with maven project structure. It is more or less a standard for mavenized projects, so used it and don't hack around it.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

In your pom.xml change the packaging to "war"

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Then update your maven project (select it in package explorer and press ALT+F5 and then close the dialog with OK)